# How can I read Euro Symbol using IText

Tags: c#, itext

I am going to convert a PDF to a Text file using iText but the Euro currency symbol is missed in the final result.

```
    public void TextExtraction()
    {
        StringBuilder allTextBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        using (PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(SourceFileName))
        using (PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(pdfReader))
        {
            for (int page = 1; page <= pdfDocument.GetNumberOfPages(); page++)
            {
                ITextExtractionStrategy strategy = new SimpleTextExtractionStrategy();
                string currentPageText = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(pdfDocument.GetPage(page), strategy);
                allTextBuilder.AppendFormat(currentPageText);
            }
        }

        File.WriteAllText(DestinationFileName, allTextBuilder.ToString(), Encoding.Unicode);
    }
```

I wonder if someone has any solution for me?

Comment: AppendFormat seems wrong.

Comment: Does it even have a overload with only one parameter?

Comment: In the `File.WriteAllText(...)` change the `Encoding.UTF8` and give it a try

Comment: None of these suggestions is working :-(

Comment: Please attach a PDF file to reproduce the problem